# Is double integration an easier way to find volume of rotation?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

AP Calculus BC student here,

One of the most hated topics from Calculus 1 & 2 is often the disk method, washer method, and the shell method.

Disk Method = $\pi \int [f(x)^2]dx$ (rotate x-axis)

Washer Method = $\pi \int [R(x)^2-r(x)^2]dx$ (rotate x-axis)

Shell Method = $2\pi \int xf(x)dx$ (rotate y-axis)

Is there a method from multivariable calculus that uses double integration to calculate the volume of rotation?

Comment: The second integral reduces to create the $\pi$ terms since a volume of rotation is symmetric around a circle

Comment: E.g. Wikipedia claims the shell method integral is derived from a double integral in polar coordinates

Comment: The Disk/Washer/Shell methods are just instances of when the double integration collapses nicely to a simple one dimensional integral (Further reading: Fubini's theorem). A general approach to surface and volume integration can be quite technical

Comment: @FShrike What I understand from your explanation is that we are integrating some Area from 0 to two pi.

Comment: Can you approach this problem without applying volume of rotation: rotate the area between the curves y=1 and y=x^2 around the x-axis.

Comment: Rotate it *around* the $x$-axis? Don't you mean around the $y$-axis? I haven't looked at problems like these in a long time so perhaps I forget the naming convention

Comment: But yes, you can doubly integrate it. You just find that the most optimal path of approach, for solids of revolution, is through the above formulae

Comment: @FShrike yes around the x-axis. The rectangles have to be perpendicular when using the washer method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are complaining that there are three methods to bear in mind when determining the volume of a body of revolution. And that, in itself, does not cover the full gamut of possibilities. I feel your pain; years ago I adopted the Pappus centroid theorems for volume and surface area of bodies of revolution.

Pappus's ($2^{nd}$) Centroid Theorem: the volume of a planar area of revolution is the product of the area $A$ and the length of the path traced by its centroid $R$, i.e., $2\pi R$. The bottom line is that the volume is given simply by $V=2\pi RA$.

And while we're here, Pappus's ($1^{st}$) Centroid Theorem: the surface area of a planar area of revolution is the product of the curve length $L$ and the length of the path traced by its centroid $R$, thus, $S=2\pi RL$.

There is no ambiguity in determining the area and centroid. (Note that the centroid of the area and line curve are *not* the same.)

Answer (score 3):

These really *are* double integrals already. They look like single integrals because one of the integrals is the integral that calculates the area or circumference of a circle, for which you have formulas. The factor of $\pi$ is a clue to that.

Comment: Can you derive the formulas from polar coordinates?

Comment: @LandryRatliff Probably. Just write the integral for the area the circular cross section in polar coordinates in the correct plane. This is just Cavalier's principle - much more useful and intuitive than more formulas. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle